# Convergence of an Integral iff another Integral Converges

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

> Let $f(x)$ be positive and continuous in $[a,\infty)$ and exists a finite limit for $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} f(x) $.
>
> Let $g(x) = 5f^{(3)}(x) + 2f(x)$
>
> Prove or disprove - $\int_{a}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ converges if and only if $\int_a^\infty g(x) dx $ converges

I thought using a comparison test, but can I prove that $g(x)$ is positive?

Thank you!

Comment: $g$ need not be positive. Assume that $$\lim_{y\to \infty} \int_a^y f(x)\,dx$$ exists. Then what would the existence of $$\lim_{y \to \infty} \int_a^y g(x)\,dx$$ imply? Is that necessarily the case if the integral of $f$ converges?

Comment: It would imply that this limit exists for the RHD as well? since the RHD consits of $f$? Thank you!

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. We have $$\int_a^y g(x)\,dx = 5 \int_a^y f^{(3)}(x)\,dx + 2\int_a^y f(x)\,dx\,.$$ The second integral on the right converges by our assumption. So what would the convergence of the first integral on the right imply?

Comment: That the LHS converges also. But how can I prove the first integral? @DanielFischer